GNU parallel freezes
I have a bash script that applies different transformation/mappings on columns of TSV file. I am trying to parallelize the transformations using GNU parallel, however my code hangs.
For simplicity consider cat, the identity mapper (i.e. input -> output), and a TSV file of three columns (generated on-the-fly using paste and seqs)
n=1000000
map=cat    # identity: inp -> out

rm -f tmp.col{1,2}.fifo
mkfifo tmp.col{1,2}.fifo
paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) \
    | tee >(cut -f1 | $map > tmp.col1.fifo) \
    | tee >(cut -f2 | $map > tmp.col2.fifo) \
    | cut -f3- \
    | paste tmp.col{1,2}.fifo - \
    | python -m tqdm > /dev/null

The above code works fine.

NOTE: python -m tqdm > /dev/null prints the speed

Next, we can parallelize the mapping tasks using GNU parallel's --pipe --keep-order arguments. Here is a minimal parallel example that works:
seq 100 | parallel --pipe -k -j4 -N10 'cat && sleep 1'

Now, putting all these together, here is my code that maps the TSV columns in parallel:
n=1000000
map=cat   # identity map: inp -> out
rm -f tmp.col{1,2}.fifo
mkfifo tmp.col{1,2}.fifo
paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) \
  | tee >(cut -f1 | parallel --id jobA --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map" > tmp.col1.fifo) \
  | tee >(cut -f2 | parallel --id jobB --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map" > tmp.col2.fifo) \
  | cut -f3- \
  | paste tmp.col{1,2}.fifo - \
  | python -m tqdm > /dev/null

This code was supposed to work, however, this code freezes.
Why does it freeze and how to unfreeze it?

Environment: Linux 5.15.0-116-generic, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on x86_64


What sort of actual processing do you perform where this bizarre arrangement makes sense?

Thanks for asking. I have a terabyte of compressed data in TSV format that I use for training ML models. I want to run some cleanup on TSV columns without creating intermediate temporary files. Here I have picked cat for demonstration, but my mapper tasks are a bit slow, and I'd like to parallelize them (reminder: no temp files, as we dont have much space and I also like to avoid disk io. I got plenty of CPU cores and RAM, so they are not the bottleneck.

I'm thinking a relatively simple Python script using multiprocessing would be a lot more straightforward, but what makes sense depends on the amount of data (in each field, and overall) and the type of processing.

Agreed and I've tried python multiprocessing already. It worked, but the performance gain by parallelizing with Python was close to FIFO/PIPE performance without parallell at all.  Python multiprocessing seemed to spend much time in inter-process-communication. background processes can't read/write to STDIN/STDOUT of the main process (expected), I need to tune buffer sizes properly, That is my plan-B, if I can't get gnu parallel to work.

It is a race condition with the fifos - not GNU Parallel
Assume this:
| tee >(cut -f1 | $map1 > tmp.col1.fifo) \
| tee >(cut -f2 | $map2 > tmp.col2.fifo) \
| cut -f3- \
| paste tmp.col{1,2}.fifo - \

Assume that $map1 prints very little and $map2 prints a lot.
paste tries to read a line from tmp.col1.fifo, but there is nothing to read, so it blocks. $map2 prints a lot to tmp.col2.fifo and fills the FIFO, so it blocks, too.
You have just been lucky that the race condition did not hit you earlier.
You can of course use temporary files to solve this, but I have the feeling you are trying to avoid that.
Maybe you can "increase" the size of the FIFO with a tool like mbuffer:
  | tee >(cut -f1 | parallel --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map" | mbuffer -q -m6M -b5 > tmp.col1.fifo) \
  | tee >(cut -f2 | parallel --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map" | mbuffer -q -m6M -b5 > tmp.col2.fifo) \
  | cut -f3- | mbuffer -q -m6M -b5 \
  | paste tmp.col{1,2}.fifo - \
  | python -m tqdm > /dev/null

But unless you know the nature of your data is not going to change, then this is a fragile solution that just kicks the can a bit further down the road.
How about this instead?
n=1000000
map=cat   # identity map: inp -> out
rm -f tmp.col{1,2,3,4}.fifo
mkfifo tmp.col{1,2,3,4}.fifo
paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) | cut -f1 | parallel --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map" > tmp.col1.fifo &
paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) | cut -f2 | parallel --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map" > tmp.col2.fifo &
paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) | cut -f3 > tmp.col3.fifo &
paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) > tmp.col4.fifo &
paste tmp.col{1,2,3,4}.fifo | python -m tqdm > /dev/null

You will run a few more pastes, but if CPU is not a problem, then this should give you no race conditions.
(Also: --id (aka. --semaphore-name) is not used with --pipe but only with --semaphore. See https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_options_map.pdf)
(Also also: If you do not need exactly 1000 entries (-N1000) then --block is faster).

OP may have the contraint to do paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n)  only once.

From the comments: I have a terabyte of compressed data in TSV format so it might be possible to simply decompress the file multiple times. Possibly a waste of CPU cycles, but if CPU cycles are not the limiting factor, it might be a worthy solution.

I did not suspect tees are the ones with deadlocks. I had added --id  to parallel thinking parallels are the ones with race condition (so assigned them diff job IDs hoping it would fix).
And @Philippe is right that I prefer to read data once (if possible), as my datasets are stored on network file system which adds extra overheads for multiple reads.  None the less, thanks for the insightful answer, @OleTange.

@ThammeGowda Can you see my now-deleted answer ? If the first paste can be done multiple times, I think you don't need the FIFOs.

I see the answer. Thats another workaround, but not pretty one. From the design point of view, I wished to separate reader code from mapper tasks, so we can change the mapper code (or optionally disable it) without touching the reader code. paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n) <(seq $n) is just a placeholder for a complicated reader (that loops over a bunch of files, does some basic sanity checks, decompresses and streams to STDOUT).

I just learned that @OleTange is the author of GNU parallel! Thanks for such a wonderful tool.

FIFO has size limitations, can you re-organize the script this way ?
#!/bin/bash

n=${1-10}
map=cat

paste <(paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n)  <(seq $n) | cut -f1 | parallel --id jobA --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map")\
      <(paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n)  <(seq $n) | cut -f2 | parallel --id jobA --pipe -k -j4 -N1000 "$map")\
      <(paste <(seq $n) <(seq $n)  <(seq $n) | cut -f3 ) \
    | python -m tqdm > /dev/null

Run with
bash test.sh 100

